# Shuffling my array

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

I'm having trouble shuffling my array, hopefully someone can guide me?

I have this array: (this array was produced from a random associate function)

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [boo] => hello
            [yeah] => world
        )    
)
```

I'm using this shuffle associate function:

```
function shuffle_assoc($list) { 
  if (!is_array($list)) return $list; 

  $keys = array_keys($list); 
  shuffle($keys); 
  $random = array(); 
  foreach ($keys as $key) { 
    $random[] = $list[$key]; 
  }
  return $random; 
}

$test = shuffle_assoc($array);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($test);
echo "</pre>";
```

And then I get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [boo] => hello // I'm trying to switch
            [yeah] => world // these two values
        )    
)
```

The shuffle function doesn't switch `[boo]` and `[yeah]`

Can someone help me?

Comment: @Kafuka Sorry, I'm using PHP. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

You need to skip the first level of the array.

```
$array = array(1 => array('boo' => 'hello', 'yeah' => 'world', 'foo' => 'bar'));
function shuffle_assoc($list) {
    foreach ($list as $idx => &$sub_array) { // we actually loop over the numeric indexes since that's the first level
        $keys = array_keys($sub_array);
        $vals = array_values($sub_array);
        shuffle($vals);
        $sub_array = array_combine($keys, $vals);
    }
    return $list;
}
$new_arr = shuffle_assoc($array);
var_export($new_arr);
```

outputs

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'boo' => 'bar',
    'yeah' => 'hello',
    'foo' => 'world',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the array you passed in is actually an array of arrays, with 1 element. You should call this method on `$array[1]`.

Also, in `shuffle_assoc`, the statement `$random[] = $list[$key]` does not preserve the key values, so the result array will only contain the values of the original array. Changing that line of code to `$random[$key] = $list[$key]` should fix the function. Below is some code that worked for me.

```
<?php
$array = array("boo" => "hello", "yeah" => "world");
function shuffle_assoc($list) { 
  if (!is_array($list)) return $list; 

  $keys = array_keys($list); 
  shuffle($keys); 
  $random = array(); 
  foreach ($keys as $key) { 
    $random[$key] = $list[$key]; 
  }
  return $random; 
}

$test = shuffle_assoc($array);

print_r($test);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

$test = shuffle_assoc(array_shift($array));

`array_shift()` brings the first element so it'll go from

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [boo] => hello
            [yeah] => world
        )    
)
```

to

```
Array
(
            [boo] => hello
            [yeah] => world
)
```

Notice how [1] is gone now